# How to delete specific array element in python

Tags: python, arrays

I do not want to delete whole row or column but with specific conditions.

What I have is like

```py
array = [[1,2,3],
         [4,5,6],
         [7,8,9]]
```

What I want is like

```
array = [5]
```

I tried to directly delete elements by using nested 'for' loop.

```py
array = [[1,2,3],
         [4,5,6],
         [7,8,9]]
    
for i in range(len(array)):
    for j in range(len(array)):
        if array[i][j] != 5:
            del array[i][j]
print(array)
```

But it does not work.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 8, in <module>
    if array[i][j] != 5:
IndexError: list index out of range
```

And even if I tried using a smaller loop range(e.g. both in range 2 instead of 3), the output is not what I want.

```
[[2], [5], [7, 8, 9]]
```

Answer (score 0):

For `list` objects, you can use the `.remove()` or the `.pop()` methods. The latter is useful if you want to retain the value. See [Python documentations](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) for more detailed information on these methods.

Here is an example:

```py
array = [[1,2,3],
         [4,5,6],
         [7,8,9]]

for row in array:
    for value in row:
        if value != 5:
            row.remove(value)

print(array)
```

```
[[2], [5], [8]]
```

The process here is as follows:

- we iterate through each row;
- we then iterate through the values in the row;
- finally, we remove the value from the row.

You might find it surprising that by removing a value from `row`, we also end up removing it from `array`. Why does this happen?

This happens because (a) lists are [immutable objects in Python](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html); and (b) because a variable containing a list (in this case `row`) is not actually an independent variable, but a reference to a specific part of our original `array`. This is a bit complicated to explain here, but a search for *weak references* and lists in Python should provide good results.

Finally, using nested loops is not the best way to do such operations in Python. I recommend you take a look at NumPy Arrays.